# I want to create a website similar to chat roulette where should I begin?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, chat, webcam

I know this sounds a little bit specific but I was just wondering where I should start, what's the best language to start from, what do I need to implement so I won't be reinventing the wheel?

Is it possibly with Ruby on rails?

Comment: Maybe you should research what you need to accomplish and then choose a language that has the best support for your goals.

Comment: First get used to looking at lots of genitalia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *start* by better defining the problem.  You can do what you want in any language that has a capable web framework, because you're going to be relying on similar client-side technologies in each rather than on specific features of the server-side language you choose.

The problem domain, however, is large, and you need to define exactly what you want to do, how to do it, and why to do it before you begin thinking about what language you should use.  (The answer to that question, of course, is `[C#|Groovy|Haskell|Java|Lisp|OCaml|Perl|Python|Ruby|Scala|Scheme]`.)

Comment: You missed quite a few languages that could do this, lol. But you're definitely on point.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn flex / actionscript for that. 
The ide for flex could be "flexbuilder"

You may develop flex with php or other language - python as an example for background procedures.